# Jitter while streaming camera

Tags: java, stream, camera, vlc, vlcj

I'm writing small application that stream video from camera(`Live! Cam sync hd creative`). I'm using `VLCj` library.
After a while in console appears

```
[0494a9bc] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (jitter of 154 ms ignored)
[0494a9bc] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
```

Application crashed at about `2000ms`

```
public class CameraServer {
    private MediaPlayerFactory factory;
    private HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private CanvasVideoSurface videoSurface;


    public CameraServer(){
        factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();

        // Create player.
        mediaPlayer = factory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();
    }

    public void start(){
        // Select input device.
        String mrl = "dshow://";
        // Tweak the options depending on your encoding requirements and audio
        String[] options = {":sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,fps=30, width=640, height=640}" + formatHttpStream("127.0.0.1", 5555), "no-sout-audio", "clock-jitter=0"};
        mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl, options);
    }

    private static String formatHttpStream(String serverAddress, int serverPort) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(60);
        sb.append(":duplicate{dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,");
        sb.append("dst=");
        sb.append(serverAddress);
        sb.append(':');
        sb.append(serverPort);
        sb.append("}}");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

I have tried different options already. What can be wrong?

EDIT

It happens only when I compile on Windows. On Linux everything works fine but It has to work on Windows.

Comment: This is likely nothing to do with vlcj itself. Did you verify what happens if you use the vlc application to play your camera with the same transcode options? Do you see the same behaviour?

Comment: From your posted code it's not clear, but are you also preventing your CameraServer instance from being garbage collected?

Comment: @caprica yes, you are right, I also have problems while streaming only with vlc.